# make fails installing SRI LM

Tags: python, installation, makefile, anaconda, srilm

I tried to install SRI LM in Anaconda Prompt and my OS is Windows but looks like I'm facing an error and couldn't see any available reference or resource in the web.

This is their official tutorial:
https://srilm-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And I'm facing error in the first step:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, WD/sbin/machine-type, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat RELEASE, ...) failed.
makefile:13: WD/common/Makefile.common.variables: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `WD/common/Makefile.common.variables'.  Stop.
```

I'm able to install and use the SRI LM with cygwin but I need to use the SRI LM in an Anaconda environment. So is there a way to use the compiled cygwin's SRILM from Anaconda python? Or any other possible method to use SRI LM in Anaconda python?

Comment: Consider running under WSL2. I.e., I wouldn't bother making this work on Windows.

Comment: Okay, but i just want to know if anyone succeeded to install this in anaconda-window, but looks like it doesn't seem feasible now.